# Paypal Return URL Payment ID

Tags: php, paypal

Good day,

I am working on a site where successful paypal payments are redirected to the return URL. The php code saves the payment id from the get variables, then it is saved in the database.

However, when I looked at the database the payments IDs look like this.

```
PAYID-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  PAY-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Is there any difference between the two payment ids? The payee id and the sale id looks the same across the table.

I found this url, but it doesn't explain the prefixes.
https://gist.github.com/scottsb/c3ba0024ebdd0101fb95ea848c184d19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between these two payments prefixes, you can handle both in the same way.